# Print an entire column from an Excel Sheet using PERL

Tags: excel, perl

I am trying to read an excel sheet and print an entire column using a perl script.
I am only able to read a row and I am unable to read a script with my script.
Here is my code :-

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use Spreadsheet::Read;

my $read = ReadData("RFQ15399_out.xlsx");
my $sheet = $read->[2];
my @row = Spreadsheet::Read::row($sheet,4);
print Dumper @row;
```

I am running short of ideas. Can anyone please help me how to read and print a column using Spreadsheet::Read.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To print a column using Spreadsheet::Read, take the sheet that you want, iterate over all the rows in that sheet, and print out the column for each row:

```
foreach my $row (1..$read->[2]{maxrow}) {

    # Assuming you want to print out the 'D' column
    # Change 4 to something else for different columns
    print $read->[2]{cell}[$row][4] 
}
```